# How to loop through json object data and split strings into variables

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a metadata object that looks like this:

```
"metadata": {
    "item0": "[id: 123][name: hello world][size: large][quanity: 2][price: $1.00]"
    "item1": "[id: 456][name: test 123][size: small][quanity: 1][price: $2.00]"
    "total": "$4.00"
}
```

I can update the format in which this metadata is displayed if it helps.

I'd like to loop through this metadata and capture `"item#"` fields to store its string data into separate variables.

Something like this:

```
const items = []

metadata.map((field) => {
    if (field.contains("item")) {
        items.push({
            id: field.id,
            name: field.name,
            size: field.size,
            quanity: field.quanity,
            price: field.price,
        })
    }
})
```

To achieve this:

```
[
    {
        id: "123",
        name: "hello world",
        size: "large",
        quanity: "2",
        price: "$1.00"
    },
    {
        id: "456",
        name: "test 123",
        size: "small",
        quanity: "1",
        price: "$2.00"
    },
]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why dont you format "[id: 123][name: hello world][size: large][quanity: 2][price: $1.00]" to be an object and not a plain string. As its now you need to write logic to extract the data from string (rregex)

Comment: hmm yes if I JSON.stringify it that might work, I'll give it a try. Thanks @munleashed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
let metadata = {
  "item0": "[id: 123][name: hello world][size: large][quanity: 2][price: $1.00]",
  "item1": "[id: 456][name: test 123][size: small][quanity: 1][price: $2.00]",
  "total": "$4.00"
}


let itemsArr = Object.keys(metadata).map(meta => {

  let splitItemKey = metadata[meta].split("][");
  let createObj = {};
  
  for(let s of splitItemKey){
    createObj[s.split(":")[0].replace("[","")] = s.split(":")[1]?.trim().replace("]","") || null;
  }
    return createObj;
});

console.log(itemsArr);
```